# Is it possible to backup my entire MacBook to Microsoft OneDrive?

Tags: macos, backup, data-synchronization, onedrive

I have a lifetime of free 5TB cloud storage on Microsoft OneDrive via my university.

Is it possible to configure things or write a script so that the entire contents of my computer are continuously backed up to OneDrive?

Thank you!
Gabriel

Comment: What do you mean with "entire content"? Your user directory, all user directories, everything on `/System/Volumes/Data`?

Comment: a Time Machine like experience would be ideal, however I know I won’t get that. So it’d be nice to back up everything except system files, for example.

Comment: Also, if 5TB is not enough for you, you can ask the IT admin if you are allowed to create groups. If you create a group the sharepoint site is 25TB I believe. I'm not sure if Arq Backup supports it though.

Comment: 5TB is enough! (for now haha.) Quite happy to have gotten so much cloud storage for free, it seems like a lot.

Answer (score 3):

A paid product that I've tried is [Arq Backup](https://www.arqbackup.com/). It supports backing up to OneDrive as well as other cloud products like Google Drive. However, it is not as fast and efficient as time machine or carbon copy cloner.

Comment: Arq is more efficient than TM or CCC as it does compression and block level deduplication. (I use Arq)

Comment: @Gilby Yes, although TM and CCC uses fsevents so they does not need to scan the entire folder / drive again. I'm not sure if Arq does that. TM and CCC also uses APFS snapshots on the backup/destination volume, and I'm not sure what Arq does in terms of that.

Comment: Here is not the place to get into a never-ending argument.  But, I do use Arq and I have upvoted your answer!  Re your last sentence: Arq uses its own storage format which does include snapshots with a restoring interface somewhat like that of Finder's with TM backups.

Comment: will Arq allow me to do rolling backups of my machine to OneDrive?

Comment: @GabrielKyne By that, you mean? I do not know the answer, but the wording of Gilby's comment seems to suggest that is a feature.